# Google Chrome will install but cancel the installation and will not launch

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, uninstall, id

I am an IT worker at a construction company and after my desktop computer did a blue-screen-of-death screen with a restore button, I clicked on it.

After that, Google Chrome will not open at all. I have ended it in Task Manager programs, re-uninstalled it which fails because the install drops and cancels entirely. I also copied the exe file to other locations on my computer and still same behavior: Chrome never acted this way on my computer before. Could someone kind of guide me on how to fix this?

I have a lot of important accounts and information on there I need to access. I also noticed that when I tried to uninstall it from apps and features it will not let me and why is it still appearing in apps and features if it's already uninstalled?

Here are more error messages for more context:

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

I also installed this from Ninite and got this error message:

> Could not verify installation.

The Ninite support guys didn't know how to help me.

I ran CC Cleaner and it did not help when clearing the Chrome files and cache.

Did this and it did not work:

> Go to local c: disk and go into program files folder and search for google. If its not there go to the "program files x86" folder and see if the google folder comes up there. And that is where Google Chrome stores its stuff so you delete that and you go to users. Then go to the account name which is the top folder then appdata then local and again look. For Google right click on it and delete it the next thing you're going to want to do is press delete.

Did this and didn't work:

> Your Chrome profile is usually left behind after uninstalling and reinstalling. If after reinstalling the browser you find you still have the problem, then the issue is likely with the user profile for that browser, in this case Chrome. I recommend doing the following to be sure it is fully reinstalled, with a fresh default user profile:
> Uninstall Chrome as before.
> Make sure Chrome is no longer located at C:\Program files (x86)\Google Chrome
> Enable hidden folders in Windows Explorer:
> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028316/windows-view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-10
> Open Windows Explorer (File Explorer), and go to the following folder:
> C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome
> Rename User Data to User Data.old
> Restart your computer
> Reinstall Chrome, using the offline installer (to make the install faster):
> https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/?standalone=1
> Also received this: C:\ Program Files\Google\Chrome\Applications\chrome.exe The specified path does not exist. Check the path and try again.

I am out of ideas, someone please help, thanks.

Comment: Is this a computer given to you by your employer for work purposes? If so, you need to talk to their designated IT support staff. If this is your own computer, please let us know. It is likely the cause of the BSOD is hardware issues, most likely related to your hard drive, and this is going to affect your ability to work with the system. Do you have backups? Because backups are the best way get back from all this.

Comment: Yes it is. I am the It support staff. How do I even do a backup of everything?

Comment: You take backups on a working machine so that when it goes bad you can repair the hardware (or other fault) and restore the backup and be done. At this point, you probably cannot get a backup, and if you did, it would be a backup of the broken things. Since you ARE the IT staff, we need a lot more information. Logs, specific error messages, any restrictions or limits imposed on the system. We presume you have local admin rights, but you need to specify this. Edit your question to make it better.

Comment: You could try importing the data from Chrome into Edge: [What's imported to Microsoft Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-edge/what-s-imported-to-microsoft-edge-ab7d9fa1-4586-23ce-8116-e46f44987ac2). If that works, can you access all the data you need by using Edge?

Comment: You need to have a backup strategy for the company. Roughly how many people work there? (A few, tens, hundreds...?)

Comment: @music2myyear You are right I will edit my question and all the error messages here so someone can help me with more information.

Comment: @Andrew Morton, hundreds...

Comment: @InformationTechnology Outside of this problem, the sensible thing to do would be to go to your manager and say something like "Hi $Manager, we need to speak to $BigBoss about getting a consultant to set up backup for our data. And check the network security." The consultant should not be a relative/friend of $Manager or $BigBoss. There is no shame in saying that you need another resource to safeguard the ongoing viability of the company—just imagine if one of those nasty ransomware groups attacked your company and, because you'd got the right people in to safeguard it you all still had a job.

Comment: @InformationTechnology OK, if you've run CCleaner then you should switch off the computer and seek professional help. *Any* use of the computer from now on will reduce the chances of getting the data back. Can you use a different computer to continue here?

Comment: I don't think setting them up with a new computer will help with this. There should be a solution for this besides giving another desktop computer. Plus they have another laptop that has chrome functioning.

Comment: @Andrew Morton, I can't go ask my manager that LOL. There is rules and politics involved.

Comment: @Andrew Morton Also basically I don't have those kinds of rights to make those choices.

Comment: @InformationTechnology 1) In the question it says "*my* desktop computer" but then you comment "setting *them* up with a new computer". I thought it was the computer you're using, not someone else's. 2) Not having those kinds of rights is what your manager is for... to get things that need more restricted rights done. 3) If you have lax IT policies then perhaps they could use [Sign in and sync in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) to transfer the data from the laptop to the desktop when you've got the desktop fixed. Is that an option?

Comment: That computer is mine its i.ts but its theirs. And that last option you metioned I have no idea to fix that. Can you kind of guide me on this procedure? LOL help and no actually its not an option. i cant do that i cant just give her another desktop i talked to my manager and also chrome wont even open on her machine.

Comment: @InformationTechnology The instructions are in the link in my comment ;)

Comment: and no actually its not an option. i cant do that i cant just give her another desktop i talked to my manager and also chrome wont even open on her machine to begin with chrome is not chroming its not letting me touch or open it because its not letting me in the middle of the installation it stops.

Comment: @InformationTechnology Did you try importing the Chrome data into Edge? That would be a really quick fix if it works - the user would simply need to use Edge.

Comment: Call it "Chrome Edge" if that makes it easier.

Comment: Nope because they arent here right now LOL I will let you know and I sense they will give me crap for not "solving the problem" but for finding a work around

Comment: @InformationTechnology A workaround can be a temporary measure to get the user working right now while you investigate how to make a permanent repair.

Answer (score 0):

If your Chrome is destroyed and you don't have enough rights on the
computer to violently cleanup after its uninstallation,
you might give up on trying to fix your Chrome installation
and use an alternative.

[Google Chrome Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable)
might be suitable replacement that will be installed side-by-side
with your non-functional existing Chrome.
Note that to recuperate your bookmarks etc. in this new installation,
this requires having had previously a login to Chrome.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say Google Chrome is  destroyed? How would I know? And how do I fix it if its destroyed? Are you saying her desktop is destroyed? What is Google Chrome Portable?

Comment: I mean that according to your description even uninstalling Chrome doesn't work, so there is a major problem. The problem might be in Windows itself, but you need administrative permissions to run utilities such as [dism](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and [sfc](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) , or even to install disk-health checking products like CrystalDiskInfo or even just to run `chkdsk`. Chrome Portable might be a solution for you, but a deeper checkup of the computer requires an administrator.

Comment: Ok I need to research how to do chkdsk because I am pretty ignorant when it comes to it. What commands should I run to help fix this? Also I am pretty ignorant when it comes to dism. I ran sfc /scannnow and that didnt help this issue. Is CrsystalDiskInfo safe I don't want Crowdstrike to flag it as malicious lol and whats the purporse of crystaldiskinfo?

Comment: Also I should have admin rights

Comment: A comment of yours seemed to say differently, but if you have admin rights, then do all the tests in my above comment. Backup all your data before that. You could install an uninstaller such as Revo Uninstaller to force the total cleanup of Chrome.

Comment: Ok, Sorry I have another question. Back up all my data before what exactly? Before installing Google Chrome portable? I have used Revo before, I will try that.

Comment: For example, if your disk's file-chains are crossed, doing `chkdsk /f` can destroy some data. DISM and SFC are usually not dangerous, but they can change stuff inside Windows with unknown results. Which is why it's better to be sure of having backups before such operations. CrsystalDiskInfo is absolutely safe and useful.